# Reporting Services User as a User Permission Key - Row level permission SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I want to create a row level permission to a report in Reporting Services. I would like to give specific users a specific access to data  - projects. A Project Manager can read data only for his projects.

I wish to limit it using SS Reporting Services Users. I only have one user - "reportviewer" who has access to sql and don't want to create more users in sql database.

But I have problem, I don't know how can I use SS Reporting Services Users (which logins are like SERVERNAME\UserName).
 I know I must have an access permission table like this one below:

**USERLOGIN              PROJECT**

SERVERNAME\Matthias    Project12

SERVERNAME\Matthias   Project13

SERVERNAME\Tommy   Project14

I wan't to have code with restrictions for user in my SQL view. something like that

```
  Where 
   (a.NrProjektu in (Select NrProjektu From tbn.SSRSRaportyDostepView Where LoginUser=USER_NAME() ) OR
        IS_ROLEMEMBER('db_owner') = 1 OR
        IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin') = 1
        )
```

But when i check USER_NAME() it is like "dbo". As I understand this "USER_NAME()" refers to sql user.

I wish to have some connection like I can use in Reporting Services report like " Where UserName=@ReportUser". I don't know how to implement in SQL.

Comment: Can you remove the story-problem/background part of your post and consolidate your actual problem down to a direct/succinct question? This is kind of a lot of reading/analyzing/interpreting to ask of someone trying to help you for free in their spare time. If you are aware of links to official documentation to support any statements you are basing your assumptions on, embed those as hyperlinks. Etc. Make this more readable/digestable by someone who's trying to help you for free.

Comment: For example, I see no point to most of this post. I almost think you could literally paste some SQL where you call USER_NAME() and show it outputting 'dbo' and then asking 'WTF?' with a link to some documentation showing that it's supposed to be something else.

Comment: Hi Bane thank you for your opinion. I made my description longer as it started gaining negative points. At the begining it was very short. The case was more complex in my opinion and people didn't know what I meant (I wanted to implement ReportServer Login of current report user rendering a specific report in SQL view actually.)  and I wanted to avoid solutions which I knew i.e. implementing row level permission using a user parameter in report. But after all I made myself confirmed thanks to @niktrs that this solution it is not bad. I did what he suggested after all. And I'm grateful.

Comment: my advice still holds. Your post is difficult to understand quickly. You can still add the background at the bottom of your post, if you think that context helps readers (which I agree, it sometimes DOES), but the core of your post should be more direct without all the rambling. Anyways, I'm glad you got your answer but as you can see your question is not going to be reusable by anyone coming behind you.

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that your post SHOULD have included what you already actually thought of or tried and why you don't think that answers your question. Doing so might have gotten you more up votes, more understanding, and more immediate assurances that your solution is actually the best; or having seen you tried that, it may have changed @niktrs answer. In any regard, it would have drastically improved the reusability of your question prior to anyone else even answering you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a parameter eg. usr and make it internal.

Set the parameter expression `= User!UserID`

On your dataset join the project data table with the user permissions table filtering using the user parameter like below

```
SELECT p.*
FROM ProjectData AS p
INNER JOIN UserPermissions AS u ON p.project = u.project 
WHERE u.username = @usr
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution I understand, but I'm looking for something different. I use a procedure to generate data to raport. I thought I could implement a code in my source view from which the procedure gets data. This would help me to avoid implementing the code with permission in every report sharing data from the one view.